# How to access a url using ajax from another url, same server just different domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have a server that is hosting 2 different domains, as far as I know I can't initiate a request from one domain on another using Javascript. So I am wondering how I can get around to do this?

What I'm trying to get done is on load get the json from the other url and then process it with javascript in the current url. So far I only have a button (a form with pre-filled input fields) that when you click it it takes me to the other url but I haven't figured out how can I make it so that it a) loads automatically and b) won't take me to the other site just fetch the data and return it to me. My approach always ends up in ajax which I can't do. Any ideas?

Comment: Same server, but different domains?! Same physical server? ;)

Comment: yep, same physical server, just it hosts several domains

Answer (score 0):

You can have your JS add a `<script>` tag which loads the data (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: question, after I load the data in the `<script>` how can I access it now? I'm asking because I get the following message: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html."

Comment: Sounds like you need to set the mime headers to text/javascript or application/json

Comment: @mplungjan I can't really change them on the script that's returning the data just on the file I'm working on, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution caould be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (as suggested by rczajka) or in your case - since you have access to the other server, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) - here is the explanation from [MDN](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

> The browser will request data from the domain's server by sending an
>   Origin header with the value of the origin. It will only complete the
>   connection if the server responds with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   header of either * or the exact URL of the requesting page. Web-server
>   from another domain must send response header:

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx